# Architecture of IoT with PII Protection Regulation (e.g. GDPR)

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, iot, pii

I have a hard time searching for a reference architecture for IoT that specifies a way of reaching PII Protection regulation compliance (e.g. GDPR). There are lots of articles with general suggestions like [this](https://www.i-scoop.eu/internet-of-things-guide/iot-regulation/) or [this](https://internetofbusiness.com/gdpr-10-steps-to-prepare-iot-projects-expert-panel/), but what I am really seeking is a specific architecture design.

Say, taking Google Cloud Platform as an example, there is the following reference architecture ([link](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/iot/)): 
[image]
It does not tell anything about the PII protection, but I can think about implementing or taking a COTS tokenization service ([a security gateway](https://www.protegrity.com/data-security-gateway/)), which then shall be deployed to the Edge (which is located in the same country, where a personal information has to be stored under the regulation rules).

1. Does this mean that IoT always has to contain some on-premise edge (playing a single entry point role for all my devices and hubs/gateways) with such the tokenization service installed (of course, for those countries that are under the regulation) if I want to have a storage layer on a public cloud only?
2. What if I need to store all telemetry that I collect from my smart home, and there is a camera that captures people coming to my door, or even a microphone that has accidentally caught my friend's words like "I am John Doe, my social security number is , and I will not be at my house, which is located at  GPS location for the next 2 days" and my system need to store them as the microphone's state? Does it mean in 'GDPR' locations I need to use on-premise storage instead of a cloud one, to be full compliant, just in case?
3. Does it all mean that if I need to design a multi-tenant multi-national business of smart homes, that includes countries under the PII Protection regulation, I must always consider a hybrid solution for data storage (on-premise + cloud) to mitigate risks like described in the previous item?

Comment: I'm not sure this can be answered objectively, because there are aspects of GDPR that have not undergone the necessary legal tests for anyone to reach reasonably-indisputable conclusions about what is and isn't permissible in many cases.  At this point, I would suggest that your questions are legal/regulatory, not technical.

Comment: Well, this is still a technical question, I believe, as the target is the architectural approach for such cases, rather than the regulatory itself. I think I'm not the first one who faced this issue, and hoped that guys who have also experienced the problem can suggest what design components could serve the three questions/scenarios I posted. Even if the solution is ad-hoc or not so objective. It is better to have a vision on possible alternatives, then nothing :)